# Chosen path already exist: Reinstalling anaconda navigator on macOS

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda, uninstallation

I have been trying to reinstall anaconda navigator on my MacBook Pro M3 pro after I deleted the previous one from the system files. Now every time I'm trying to install the package it shows:

> chosen path already exists.

I have tried to install it multiple times but it is not working. I have also tried to install the anaconda-clean package and tried to remove the files using command lines but nothing is working.

Any suggestion on this issue?